# Change date every Friday

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I need to be able to change the date automatically every Friday using javascript.
Each Friday the date will change to the next Friday.

For example the date will currently say 'Friday 25th October', at a specific time on Friday 25th October I need the date to change to 'Friday 1st November' and so on.

So each week at a specific time i set it automatically updates to the next Friday.

Comment: I'm not an expert in JS but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee532932(v=vs.94).aspx) MS document appears to show how to do date math using the JS Date object.  Hint:  don't try to figure out an algorithm to do this yourself - there are *many* pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

```
var txtFriday = $("#friday"), // a HTML id
    myDate = new Date();

// The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.
// Note: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.
if (myDate.getDay() === 5){
    //Note: If adding five days to a date shifts the month or year, the changes are handled automatically by the Date object itself!
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
}

txtFriday.text(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that on page load you run a setTimeout that should expire at your specific time that changes the shown date (and sets another setTimeout for the next Friday).

There are some caveats dealing with precision (you might want to do a setTimeout that expires significantly earlier than the desired date and run smaller length timeouts until you get your actual date).

Sample code:

```
function getNextFriday() {
    var today = new Date();
    var nextFriday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-today.getDay()+7+5);
  // TODO: change to the apropriate time
    return nextFriday;
}

window.setTimeout(changeMyDate, getNextFriday()-new Date());

function changeMyDate() {
  console.log('Time to change the date');
  window.setTimeout(changeMyDate, getNextFriday() - new Date());
}
```